# Log4j doesnot log the info in server

Tags: java, log4j

I have implemented the log4j with following properties.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to consol
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/../log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

It is working on localhost where in server side it log nothing . I guess above are the general configuration. Is there something i am missing here? I use TomEE on both client and server.Also i used the logger as following. It also does not write in local file. Only logger seems to work on client.

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Can you try using ${catalina.base} property for getting catalina file path.... log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.base}/logs/logging.log

Comment: @vishnu ,can you explain why should i used that?

Comment: The CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE environment variables are used to specify the location of Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with this line

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/../log4j-application.log
```

Please use (if you have a log folder)

```
log4j.appender.file.File=log/log4j-application.log
```

Comment: As suggest there i change the file location to folder path but nothing is there.